# c# tabcontrol - tabpage

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I am trying to add a tab page programmatically to a tabcontrol.

I can do this no problem, but it seems when I add it, it is automatically sized to only 200px in width, and I cannot work out how to resize it.  The tabpage is created in a dll, and is returned to the main client whereby it is added to the tabcontrol, but as I say when it is added it is only 200px wide, and any further controls I add onto that tabpage will not show if positioned more than 200px wide.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: How wide is the `TabControl` that you're using to host the `TabPage`? The tab page can't be wider than its host control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change the `Size` property

```
myTabControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400);
```

or the `Height` / `Width` properties

```
myTabControl.Height = 400;
myTabControl.Width = 400;
```

or the `Dock` property

```
// Size the tab control to take up all available space in parent container
myTabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```